# boost graph copy a filtered_graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

My actual intention is to use `mcgregor_common_subgraphs` to find some induced partial subgraphs. But it takes too long to compare small graphs. So instead of comparing the entire graphs I want to filter out a subset of comparable vertices and edges. Then find subgraphs between them.

So I use `filtered_graph` with vertex and edge predicates for both of these graphs. And pass the filtered graph to `mcgregor_common_subgraphs`. But it complains

```
error: use of deleted function ‘boost::iterators::filter_iterator<bya::util::isomorphism::directed_graph::vertex_filter_predicate, boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<long unsigned int> >& boost::iterators::filter_iterator<bya::util::isomorphism::directed_graph::vertex_filter_predicate, boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<long unsigned int> >::operator=(const boost::iterators::filter_iterator<bya::util::isomorphism::directed_graph::vertex_filter_predicate, boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<long unsigned int> >&)’
```

So I planned to copy the filtered graph into a new graph with `copy_graph`. But it complains that there is no default constructor for the vertex predicate `vertex_filter_predicate`.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘bya::util::isomorphism::directed_graph::vertex_filter_predicate::vertex_filter_predicate()’
```

However my vertex and edge predicate takes a `const reference` to the original graph. So I cannot add an empty default constructor. I have searched in boost documentation, but didn't find any example of copying a `filtered_graph`. What is the solution ? Also why would `copy_graph` require the predicates to copy ?

```
struct directed_graph{
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, vertex_data, edge_data> graph_type;
    graph_type _graph;
    // ...
};
```

I have a directed graph struct inside which I have the predicates and equivalance comparators. Both small and large are instances of `directed_graph`.

```
directed_graph::edge_filter_predicate   edge_filter_small  (small._graph, allowed_vertex_ids), edge_filter_large  (large._graph, allowed_vertex_ids);
directed_graph::vertex_filter_predicate vertex_filter_small(small._graph, allowed_vertex_ids), vertex_filter_large(large._graph, allowed_vertex_ids);

boost::filtered_graph<directed_graph::graph_type, directed_graph::edge_filter_predicate, directed_graph::vertex_filter_predicate> filtered_small_view(small._graph, edge_filter_small, vertex_filter_small);
boost::filtered_graph<directed_graph::graph_type, directed_graph::edge_filter_predicate, directed_graph::vertex_filter_predicate> filtered_large_view(large._graph, edge_filter_large, vertex_filter_large);

directed_graph::graph_type filtered_small;
boost::copy_graph(filtered_small_view, filtered_small);
```

Comment: Where's your code? I have done this, but the fact that your error implies to copying the filter predicate suggests that the target type is also a filtered graph? That doesn't seem correct then.

Comment: An example where I used this before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011373/need-to-find-sub-graphs-from-one-big-graph-using-boostgraph/48016277#48016277

Comment: I have added the related code fragments.